Is there a way to transfer a module in Python into a remote location?
Is it possible to serialize any 3rd party, non-standard module like for example the colorama module, along with all its dependencies, from a server where it is installed, and then transfer it using sockets into a client and then import it on the client where it is not installed, all while using memory only and without any client disk access?

In principle, yes. (However I'm not sure how the module and all its dependencies got into the server's memory without loading them from disk.)

What about in practice?

With enough time and effort also in practice.

Are you familiar with anyone who has already implemented it, closest thing I could find is RPyC but it executes objects locally, which means the execution of the modules would happen on the server-side. and then the result would be sent to the client.

I feel like importlib is part of what you are looking for
